# clearInterval by passing a stop function in parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am streaming ajax calls, and I wanted to stop the stream if the "left" key was pressed. However, this function `stream_ajax` is a template which I use many times throughout my code, so I wanted to pass a `clearInterval` statement which would detect whether the "left" key was pressed.

```
function stop() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

function stream_ajax(callback, stop) {
    stream = setInterval(
        function(){
            // get page
        },
        10000
    );
    if(stop() == false) {
        clearInterval(stream);
    }
}
```

My code doesn't seem to work, I was able to get the callbacks working through the same method. Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass the stream to `stop`, and do the `clearInterval` in the keydown handler, like so:

```
function stop(stream) {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            clearInterval(stream);
        }
    });
}

function stream_ajax(callback, stop) {
    stream = setInterval(
        function(){
            // get page
        },
        10000
    );

    if (stop)  // in case no stop function was passed in
      stop(stream);
}
```

Comment: +1. Closer to the original code than my answer. Note that if `stop()` is called repeatedly it will bind more and more keydown handlers, so it might be a good idea to include a call to `.off()` just before `.keydown()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not sure I follow, do you mean what you did in your code? If I used return false after `clearInterval(stream);` would it be the same thing?

Comment: `$(document).off("keydown").keydown(...` or something like in my answer. Returning false cancels the default behaviour for the current event, it doesn't remove the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your `stop()` function doesn't explicitly return a value, which means it always returns `undefined`. The `return false` that you have is inside the keydown handler function, not part of `stop()`. The `.keydown()` method assigns a new keydown handler, it doesn't test whether a key has been pressed in the past.

You could do something like this:

```
function stream_ajax(callback, stop) {
    var stream = setInterval(
        function(){
            // get page
        },
        10000
    );
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            clearInterval(stream);
            $(document).off("keydown");
        }
    });
}
```

That is, bind a keydown handler right after setting the interval, and within that handler if the key you care about is pressed clear the interval and remove the keydown handler.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, I was hoping for a completely external function, so Paul Roub got the right answer. Thanks for your time nnnnnn, I seriously appreciate it!